# Webpack CSS to constructable stylesheet

Tags: javascript, webpack, shadow-dom, constructable-stylesheet

Chrome v73. Webpack v4.29.6.

I am trying to wrap an ag-grid in a web component with a shadow dom. In order to do so, I need to load the theme .css files in the context of shadow dom.

I want to do this as a module import via a `Constructable Stylesheet`. I know these are a fairly new concept, but is there anything in webpack that will take a css file and as part of an `import` convert it to a exported `Constructable Stylesheet` javascript module that is then imported as part of the webpack build

Comment: Are you using any class helpers like LitElement or Stencil, or composing your web-components with vanilla JS? I've accomplished what you are trying with the help of some LitElement functionality and a couple small tools, notably `wc-sass-render` (to make your styles into a JS module you can import) and `static get styles()` that is LitElement's stylesheet constructor which will put your imported style into the component's shadow-root's adoptedStylesheets.